# Escape velocity for particle on pole of a rotating, spherical planet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, escape-velocity

I got a book called "Problems and Solutions in Mechanics" and decided to try some problems.

Here is problem 1008

> 1008. Consider a rotating spherical planet. The velocity of a point on its
>       equator is $v$. The effect of rotation of the planet is to make $g$ at
>       the equator $1/2$ of $g$ at the pole. What is the escape velocity for
>       a polar particle on the planet expressed as a multiple of $v$?

First of all, why would the gravitational acceleration be different at different points of a spherical planet?

Here is the solution from the solution manual, with my comments and questions

> Let $g$ and $g'$ be the gravitational accelerations at the pole and at
> the equator, respectively and consider a body of mass $m$ on the
> surface of the planet, which has a mass $M$.

Aren't the gravitational accelerations the same at any point on the surface of this planet? Why would $g$ and $g'$ be different?

> At the pole,
>
> $$mg=\frac{GMm}{R^2}$$
>
> giving
>
> $$GM=gR^2$$
>
> At the equator, we have
>
> $$\frac{mv^2}{R}=\frac{GMm}{R^2}-mg'=mg-\frac{mg}{2}=\frac{mg}{2}\tag{1}$$

I don't follow. What does $\frac{GMm}{R^2}-mg'$ express? It seems to be $F_g-mg'$. But what force is $mg'$ expressing?

> Hence $g=\frac{2v^2}{R^2}$.
>
> If we define gravitational potential energy with respect to a point at
> infinity from the planet, the body will have potential energy
>
> $$-\int_\infty^R -\frac{GMm}{r^2}dr=-\frac{GMm}{R}$$
>
> Note that the negative sign in front of the gravitational force takes
> account of its attractiveness.

What does "attractiveness" mean in this context?

> The body at the pole then has total energy
>
> $$E=\frac{mv^2}{2}-\frac{GMm}{R}$$

How is this expression obtained? $\frac{mv^2}{2}$ is the kinetic energy of the equator particle that is assumed to have speed $v$. How does this apply to the particle at the pole?

> For it to escape the planet, its total energy must be at least equal
> to the minimum energy of a body at infinity, ie zero. Hence the escape
> velocity $w$ is given by
>
> $$\frac{mw^2}{2}-\frac{GMm}{R}=0$$
>
> or
>
> $$w^2=\frac{2GM}{R}=2gR=4v^2$$
>
> $$w=2v$$

Here is what I see in the problem

- A particle on the pole is not rotating. There is a gravitational force $$\frac{GMm}{R^2}$$ and a normal force of equal magnitude, and these cancel out.
- If this particle were not touching the ground, but rather in free fall, then we'd have $\frac{GMm}{R^2}=mg_{pole}$, and so $g_{pole}=\frac{GM}{R^2}$.
- A particle at the equator is rotating about the axis passing through the pole. The forces on the particle are the gravitational force and a normal force applied by the ground. The radial acceleration is $\vec{a}_R=-R\omega^2\hat{r}=-\frac{v^2}{R}\hat{r}$ and applying Newton's 2nd Law we have that

$$\frac{mv^2}{R}=\frac{GMm}{R^2}-N$$

What am I missing in this problem?

Comment: _Aren't the gravitational accelerations the same at any point on the surface of this planet? Why would g and g′ be different?_, because $g' = g - a_c$ is **reduced**  gravitational acceleration due to Earth centrifugal force (in magnitude same as centripetal acceleration). If Earth is not assumed to be an ideal sphere, but ellipsoid instead- then you have to include also the effect of different radius of Earth at pole and equator, which affects local $g(r)$.